# Java: displaying photo images in a photo viewer

Tags: java, android, facebook

My goal is to make a java program that will make a tablet/phone act as a photo frame.
I guess I will need a class for each of these objectives:

(1) Load an image from some stored location and display it
(2) Import photo album from facebook and store it locally - to display as described above(1).
(3) Apply transition effects for (1)

I thought this would be easy to do - but am struggling....

Thanks

Jenny

Comment: This is too vague. At least create an application first and try to make it with the widgets that's already provided.

Comment: Please provide some code or what you have tried so far.  SO members will be glad to help you find/fix problems, but they cannot tell you how to write an entire app.